# Recurring mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have php form in which you can submit your income / expenditure (basic home budget management). In order to have them auto repeat every month I use code as below

```
INSERT INTO income (ammount, date, desc, category)
SELECT ammount, now(), desc, category FROM income WHERE recurring=1 and date LIKE '____-__-23'
```

Recurring is always 0 or 1(tinyint) to differentiate one time from recurring income/exp. It all works fine except for the fact that i have 62 php scripts added to cron (31 for income and 31 for expenditure - 1 each for each day of the month). Is there any better solution to that ? Not looking for complete solution - just point me into right direction. Thanks.

Comment: You've got 31 scripts for income, one for every day of the month and the only difference between them is the end of the LIKE clause? Is that your problem?

Comment: Yes - that is correct

Comment: I'm disappointed you didn't figure out you could write one script with a variable in it. Remember computers are supposed to make life easier for you. If they're not try and evaluate your strategy to see if you're going against the grain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function called `DAY` (synonymous to `DAYOFMONTH`), which extracts the day of month from the date field. This means that you can change

```
 date LIKE '____-__-23'
```

to

```
DAYOFMONTH(date) = DAYOFMONTH(NOW())
```

You will no longer need one script for each day of the month.

Remember not to run those queries just before midnight.

If you want to learn more, read the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth).

Comment: That's what I was looking for - guess its time to read more documentation. Thank you.